# How does the PostgreSQL user configuration work on MacOSX?

Tags: macos, postgresql, unix

I just installed Postgres 9.4 ([EnterpriseDB package](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#osx)) and I am confused by the users I see in the system.

If I print `/etc/passwd` I see the `_postgres` user:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep postgres
_postgres:*:216:216:PostgreSQL Server:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
```

But if I try to login with it I am still identified with my user.

```
$ su _postgres
Password:
$ whoami
motta
```

The weird behavior is that I can login with the `postgres` user even if this is not listed in `/etc/passwd`

```
$ su postgres
Password:
$ whoami
postgres
```

This is really strange to me.
Could someone explain what's going on?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> _postgres:*:216:216:PostgreSQL Server:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false

The last component of this `/etc/passwd` entry is the shell to use for that user. If it was something like `/bin/sh` it would work as you expect (compare with the entry for `postgres` without the underscore. EDIT: actually no, don't bother, because it may not be there).

Since it's `/usr/bin/false` it immediately terminates and gives control back to the caller instead of waiting for shell commands.

It implies that `_postgres` as a user is not meant to be used for shell access.

Comment: thanks, got it now. But where is the `postgres` user coming from (without the _ prefix)? It is not in my `/etc/passwd` file. If I do `cat /etc/passwd | grep "postgres"` I only got the `_postgres` entry.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I recall that I've been surprised by this before and this question: [Users in /etc/passwd on Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/questions/191330) helped me figure out that `/etc/passwd` is not the right place on OS X for non-system accounts.

Comment: Also, mention what postgres package you installed. There are many different [postgres packages](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/) for OSX, several of them don't even create/use a dedicated postgres user.